# Setting Up Snapping Environment Snapping Type using ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, snapping

I try to setup snapping environment snapping type by referring to this source (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001s1000000) but I can't combine the snapping type like the example. It gives me **Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls.esriSnappingType' and 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls.esriSnappingType'**

What could be the problem or is there another approach to achieve this?

I try to do this using C# and ArcGIS Engine 10.1.

Comment: I think it's a bitwise addition (like other constants) perhaps use *&* operator. Please post code that's causing the problem.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do:

snappingEnvironment.SnappingType = esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypePoint + esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeEndpoint + 
                esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeVertex + esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeEdge;

Comment: Esri snapping type constants http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0016000000r2000000 are bits in a byte. Use esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypePoint & esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeEndpoint & esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeVertex & esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeEdge

Comment: @Michael Miles-Stimson Bitwise OR (|) should be used, not AND (&). But + should work fine too.

Comment: Doh! It's been too long since I've done binary operators; 1992 was when I studied Logic. You're absolutely correct @r.pankevicius 0 & 1 = 0 but 0 | 1 = 1, the object is to combine the bits so a binary IOR (Inclusive OR) is what's needed, of course *int*ing the type constant tells the compiler that it's a number and can be used as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast them to ints, add them and recast back to esriSnappingType, like:

```
snappingEnvironment.SnappingType = (esriSnappingType)
    ((int)esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypePoint +
     (int)esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeEndpoint +
     (int)esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeVertex +
     (int)esriSnappingType.esriSnappingTypeEdge);
```